# How many of the world's PCs has the Office 2007 compatibility pack installed (docx, xlsx etc)?

Tags: windows, microsoft-office, compatibility

Is there any way to find out how many PCs have the compatibility pack installed? We're planning to end distribution of office 2003 (.doc .xls) files, and even though a considerable number of users have office 2003 or earlier installed they wil still be able to view and edit (not everything) docx and xlsx files with the compatibility pack.

Has it been included in any major service pack?

Comment: The question, you are really interested in, seems to be *"How many of our customers/users have the compat. pack installed?"* and this is something that may be very different from the whole world.

Comment: Do you need to send out editable files? If not, maybe changing the workflow to send out PDFs instead might be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Why? Only because is it the Microsoft's new solution?

Always use most compatible formats to allow users to open documents in any way, not just Microsoft way! Users from another OS or that have no money to buy MS Office will thank.

Open Office can open and edit DOCX, XLSX etc. but pehaps some formatting erros may occurr.

Google Docs has some problems with some documents in those formats.

So, use popular formats DOC and XLS and make users of other solutions than Microsoft be happy :)

Comment: Thanks for the speech. Not really the answer to my question though. All my users have Microsoft Office installed, so I don't really consider the other options. Maybe it is a shame, but it is reality.

Comment: Well, ok for your PCs. But why are you asking about world PC's? Only to compare your solution with other companies? Ok then. But if the world PC's are using DOCX and XLSX, it is the wrong way. XLSX and DOCX are from M$. It is best to use more "free" and known solutions XSL and DOC. About compatibility pack, I use and approve it, but I think it is not included in any M$ Windows update. Pehaps in optional updates from windowsupdate.microsoft.com... Search and download it on microsoft.com.